# While Editing the GridView, dropdownlist values are not storing in the variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

values of selected items in dropdownlist(edit gridview) are returning NULL. It should return selected values..

Code in aspx.cs file::

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList ct = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList6");
    string ctype = ct.SelectedItem.Text;
    string sql1 = ("Select Case_Type_Value FROM Case_Type where Case_Type_Text ='" + ctype + "' ");


    DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList3");
    string cstatus = cs.SelectedItem.Text;
    string sql2 = ("Select Case_Status_Value FROM Case_Status where Case_Status_Text ='" + cstatus + "' ");


    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);

    con.Open();
    int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close(); 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET Case_Type = @Case_Type, Case_Status = @Case_Status, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Type", v1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case_Status", v2);
```

Below is the aspx code for the page:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333" width="1000px"
                GridLines="None"  OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                BorderStyle="Outset" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Cambria" 
                Font-Size="Small" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
               >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Number" SortExpression="case_number">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_number") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Name" SortExpression="case_name">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Type" SortExpression="Case_Type_Text">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Case_Type_Text" 
                                DataValueField="Case_Type_Text" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Case_Type_Text") %>'>
                                <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Case_Type_Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Status" SortExpression="Case_Status_Text">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Case_Status_Text" DataValueField="Case_Status_Text" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Case_Status_Text") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned Date" SortExpression="assigned_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("assigned_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("assigned_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned To" SortExpression="assigned_to">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="User_Name" 
                                DataValueField="User_Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("assigned_to") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("assigned_to") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Withdrawn" SortExpression="date_withdrawn">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker5" runat="server" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                                CalendarDate='<%# Bind("date_withdrawn") %>' TextCssClass="" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_withdrawn", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Delivered" SortExpression="date_delivered">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker7" runat="server" 
                                CalendarDate='<%# Bind("date_delivered") %>' TextCssClass="" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("date_delivered", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC By" SortExpression="qc_by">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="User_Name" DataValueField="User_Name" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_by") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QC Date" SortExpression="qc_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <cc1:DatePicker ID="DatePicker6" runat="server" 
                                CalendarDate='<%# Bind("qc_date") %>' TextCssClass="" 
                                />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qc_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Additional Notes">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("additional_notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" 
                        CausesValidation="False" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you update question with aspx page gridview markup? and in which event are you find controls?

Comment: As Damith said , "In which event are you find controls" ?

Comment: GridView1_RowUpdating

Comment: try with `DropDownList cs =GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList`

Comment: ERROR::: are you missing a cast?

Comment: what happen @AnkitGoyal ,

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam.. Can we start chat??

Answer (score 0):

Try likes this ,

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
DropDownList ct = (DropDownList)row.Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList6");
string ctype = ct.SelectedValue;

DropDownList cs = (DropDownList)row.Cell[3].FindControl("DropDownList3");
string cstatus = cs.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Not working.. Already tried that..
I am using for Row::::  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

Comment: What you have edited in the code, can you tell me..?? because i am viewing the old code..

Comment: `row.FindControl` to `row.Cells[cellIndex].FindControl` And `ct.SelectedItem.Text` to `ct.SelectedValue` !

Comment: how can i get cell index??

Comment: (column position of your DropDownList ) - 1 . It's better if you can show your aspx code of your GridView !

Comment: your `DropDownList6` is in index `2` and `DropDownList3` is in index `3` ,

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewRow row = grdVw.Rows[e.RowIndex];
String str = Convert.ToString(((DropDownList)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).SelectedItem);
```

Get your cell number ,Numbering for cells start from zero so it will be 2 for DropDownList6 in your code .

Please check and verify if it works !

Comment: ERROR::: {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'."}

Comment: Yes you have two controls in one cell one Label and one dropdown !My Bad so you are getting this error ,Control[0] is , **O** tells the location of control.     Try this                                                          **String str = Convert.ToString(((DropDownList)(row.Cells[2].FindControl("drpdwn6"))).SelectedItem);**

Comment: One more thing you can try try Control[1] in above code ,As it is taking label control at 0th position .